# VBA Access Error displayed but nothing in the code

Tags: vba, ms-access

It's my first time using VBA and Access even if I'm coming from Angular and Swift, I'm completely lost.

I'm modifying an existing project and I have created a text label and used the expression generator, then the application crashed. I obviously think that there is a problem in the "expression" that I generated.

The problem is now that I cannot access to the Form where I was working and I get this message :

[image]

I have tried to go to the code but I haven't found my problematic expression. **Do access store somewhere else the code generated, especially for the expressions generated? How can I find again my problematic expression?**

In the code I found, I didn't find any object declaration, for example, as a TextBox...I tried to compile all code, since this is a syntax error, it should be easier to find and solve but it didn't work at all, the compile and run didn't show me any syntax error, I tried to change some settings to handling error but no success...

So if someone could tell me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's not in the VBA code, it may be in the properties of a text box, etc. Try opening the form in design mode (Right-click, "design mode"), open the properties view (right-click on a field, "properties"), and look at the properties for the various text boxes, for something similar.

Comment: for anyone looking at this. google translated: **Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression (=Forms![FormCivilWorks]!Budgets_Tabular.Form!Budget_ID)**

Comment: @GregHNZ I tried it too, the problem is I cannot access the UI form in design mode before I perform a click and the click event display the error, to be more accurate, I have a Form 1 who's fully functional, I click on it to access the Form 2(where I had added a bug...) but I cannot access and an error is displayed

Comment: To be more accurate, Form2 is not a form, it is a REPORT, did Access store reports in a special directory? Because in the code generated I didn't see anything related to reports...